# linq on a DataTable giver compilation error

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable

I am triyng to get distinct values from a populated datatable but I cannot get it compiling. I found some code on stackoverflow but it will not compile.
So, what is wrong with this example :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dt.Rows
                    select new { col1 = dRow["Col1"] }).Distinct();
```

I know this code wil not return anything because dt is empty, but its just to show you the linq I am trying to use and to avoid questions like "show me the code for your table" I simply want to know why I cannot compile this in visual studio 2013, c#, framework 4.5

The compiler returns :

> Error 127 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\GTT\TFS\Test_App\Test
>   app\FormRitLegeCMRList.cs 64  33  Palm
>
> Error 128 Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' C:\GTT\TFS\Test_App\Test
>   app\FormRitLegeCMRList.cs 64  33  Palm

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, got it fixed now. But one thing I do not understand, why the downvote on my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from adding `using System.Linq;` as pointed out by @Sriram [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28456402/961113).

It appears that you are interested in distinct values for a particular column, there is no need to project to anonymous type (with new keyword). You can also have your query like:

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Col1"))
    .Distinct();
```

But you have to specify type for `Col1` in `Field` extension method. You can also do:

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row["Col1"])
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Do you have any idea why I got a downvote on my queston ? One is afraid to ask things here these days...

Comment: @fubo, it is not a copy of Sriram's answer, but his answer should be accepted, IMO. It is upto OP (GuidoG)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have added the using statement `System.Linq` at the top of your cs file. That should solve it.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: `using System.Linq;` is definitely the cause of error. +1